# Gradle project refresh failed - cause error in opening zip file

Tags: linux, gradle, android-studio

Im using Back Track r3 and android studio 0.8.6, every time i start a project i get
"Gradle project refresh failed - cause error in opening zip file"
error message, what can i do to fix it?

update:

after trying to delete /gradle folder in plugins
this is what i get. [image]

only more errors i cant rebuild the project

Comment: Your errors in loading Android Studio plugins could be due to a corrupted Android Studio installation. You can try reinstalling. I'm not sure why you're having all these corruption problems.

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in the .gradle directory in your home directory, and also the .gradle directory in your project, and rebuild.

The rebuild will take some time because it will need to re-download a bunch of Gradle and project dependencies, but I think one of those has become corrupted.

Comment: i tried but when i reopened android studio i get more errors and frankly i do not know how to rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Old, but had it today on a react native generated project :

so I deleted the content of the `gradle` dir at the root (`myproject-dir/android/gradle`) of the android project -> it redownloaded everything, and it was fine !

Hope this will help someone.